# Can't train sagemaker model using recordio protobuf data saved in S3

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-sagemaker

I want to preprocess data in Amazon EMR using PySpark and train a machine learning model in SageMaker using pipe mode. The issue I am having now is saving data in S3 and feeding it to the model.

SageMaker models accept the application/x-recordio-protobuf type. Therefore, I have saved my data as:

```
output_path = f"s3://my_path/output_processed"
df_transformed.write.format("sagemaker").mode("overwrite").save(output_path)
```

Where `df_transformed` is a `pyspark dataframe`.

When I am trying to feed my data to the model:

```
records = RecordSet(s3_data=train_path, s3_data_type='S3Prefix', num_records=-1, feature_dim=50) rcf.fit(records)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Failed. Reason: ClientError: Unable to read data channel 'train'. Requested content-type is 'application/x-recordio-protobuf'. Please verify the data matches the requested content-type. (caused by MXNetError)
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? And is it necessary to preprocess data separately in EMR and train in `SageMaker`, or can I just do everything in SageMaker? (Considering the cost).

Tutorial I followed: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-pipe-input-mode-for-amazon-sagemaker-algorithms/

Comment: Does `train_path` equal to `output_path`?

Comment: @LioniaVasilev Yes

Answer (score 0):

change the format of Saving data in RecordIO format:-

```
output_path = f"s3://my_path/output_processed"
df_transformed.write.format("recordio").mode("overwrite").save(output_path)
```

and use:-

```
records = RecordSet(s3_data=train_path, s3_data_type='S3RecordIO', num_records=-1, feature_dim=50) rcf.fit(records)
```

refer:-

Using Pipe input mode for Amazon SageMaker algorithms: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-pipe-input-mode-for-amazon-sagemaker-algorithms/

Preprocessing data for Amazon SageMaker: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/processing-job.html

If the cost is considered then it is better to go with SageMaker.

**But** if the **dataset is large** and **pre-processing** of the data logic is **complex** and if the code is **already implemented in EMR** infrastracture then changing it into SageMaker **would be costing more.**

refer:-

Amazon SageMaker cost optimization guide: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/optimizing-costs-for-machine-learning-with-amazon-sagemaker/

Amazon EMR cost optimization guide: https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/

Comment: Did you make sure that your code works? When I do this:
df_transformed.write.format("recordio").mode("overwrite").save(output_path)
I get: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: recordio.

Comment: yeah it is working. i guess you must be checking the system read access permissions for accessing the record files and once verify the path as sometimes it is where the problem is found and trye to run in an venv environment